# Unable to receive UDP packets from Amazon EC2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2, udp

I have an amazon ec2 server with all necessary ports opened and configured firewall. Server application listening on certain port for client's data and responding with ack. But it looks like server receiving the data, then sending ack, but client doesn't receiving it. And it works when I tried to start the server and the client apps on two different ec2 instances, but if the client is started somewhere outside of Amamzon, then ack packets never reach it.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic troubleshooting:

> it looks like server receiving the data and responding with ack

Er, "looks like"? Did you run TCPDump on the server to verify that the response was actually sent? (And verify that it was sent to the correct IP/port, etc.)

Did you run TCPDump on the client to see if the packet was received by the OS, but somehow not delivered to the app? (`tcpdump -ni eth0 udp port 9999`)

Are you using AWS VPC? (VPC firewall can block outgoing packets)

Are there other firewalls involved? (I.e. a home router doing NAT/STUN/etc.) Can you try it on another "naked" server outside of Amazon?

Can you use `netcat`'s UDP mode to verify it's not specific to your code?

Can you use `netcat`'s UDP mode on other ports to verify it's not specific to one UDP port?

Comment: This is a Windows server. VPC is disabled. And as I said - it works between two amazon servers and between two non-amazon computers.

Comment: I have a firewall on client side, but I thought this firewall should pass all "response" udp packets back, am I right? In other words, I'm sending udp packet from client with local address 192.168.1.10:50000 to the server with global address 54.54.54.54:44444... So, my router creates record with my local address and assign temporal global address, something like 33.33.33.33:56784. Now, all packets from server 54.54.54.54:44444 to 33.33.33.33:56784 will be forwarded to the client's local address even if all ports on routers's firewall or my computer's firewall are closed. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's typically how they work, but never assume anything. Home routers vary wildly in practice. Some have very short timeouts (a minute or two) for recognizing the response, some will drop responses when they have more than a few dozen connections, etc. Also, some home ISPs filter various "dangerous" UDP ports for you.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. But if I won't assume that, then how can I send data back to the client? In other words, you said that in some cases I won't be able to send anything back and this means that duplex udp communication is impossible, moreover such configuration won't be able to work with any udp based protocol. Is it true? But in this case how applications like Skype works? As for me, I use sever only for hole punching purpose, but in some situations even client<->server udp communication doesn't work properly :(

Comment: @Tutankhamen have you resolved this issue? If so, how?

Comment: Nope, some amazon servers have this issue, but some don't. It has relation to server's location. For example, I had no problem with servers in North California, but servers in Washington didn't work.